# Is it possible to parse dates with both TextStyle.SHORT and TextStyle.FULL for the month?

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-8, java-time

A Java 8 `DateTimeFormatter` created from a pattern like `d. MMM u` can only parse dates with the month written in the style defined by TextStyle.SHORT (e.g. `13. Feb 2015`), a DateTimeFormatter created from `d. MMMM u` can only parse dates with the month written in the style defined by TextStyle.FULL (e.g. `13. February 2015`).

In the "old" SimpleDateFormat, the difference between "MMM" and "MMMM" was only important for formatting, not for parsing, so it was easily possible to create a parser that understood both the FULL and the SHORT form of month names.

Is it possible to create a Java 8 DateTimeFormatter that can also do this? Or do I always have to create two parsers, one with the FULL and one with the SHORT pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make the different *month* patterns optional:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d. [MMMM][MMM] u HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);

    ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("4. Jan 2015 00:00:00 UTC", formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("4. January 2015 00:00:00 UTC", formatter);

    System.out.println(zdt1);
    System.out.println(zdt2);
```

Output:

```
2015-01-04T00:00Z[UTC]
2015-01-04T00:00Z[UTC]
```

**EDIT**

This formatter can only be used for `parse()`, you will have to use a different one for `format()`.

Comment: Ok, the only downside I see to this is that it can now parse "broken" strings like "15. JanuaryJan 2015", but that's not really a big problem. Still undecided if having two Formatters/Parsers might not be the more elegant solution...

Comment: @David I'd say if you just have two, it doesn't really matter which solution you choose. But if there's a possibility you'll need to parse more types of formats, you should probably choose one parser and one formatter (you can even nest the optional parts).